# How to always generate `Table` constructors for JOOQ 3.11's implicit-join feature?

Tags: code-generation, jooq

JOOQ 3.11 introduced an awesome feature called [implicit joins](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/06/07/jooq-3-11-released-with-4-new-databases-implicit-joins-diagnostics-and-much-more/).

Unfortunately, the new feature causes trouble with our half-baked application modularization.

**Symptom**

Looking at the [JOOQ generator source code](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/b396cded8600165ae77f1b12303a3952a9ddf58b/jOOQ-codegen/src/main/java/org/jooq/codegen/JavaGenerator.java#L3883), I found out that the following constructor for the generated class `FileStorage` (a `Table` subclass) are generated only if the JOOQ generator finds a foreign key referencing `FILE_STORAGE`:

```
public <O extends Record> FileStorage(Table<O> child, ForeignKey<O, FileStorageRecord> key) {
    super(child, key, FILE_STORAGE);
}
```

This leads to compilation errors in our build that generates the JOOQ model for each application module separately:

We use one schema per application-module (e.g. `billing`) and one special schema `shared` that is visible from every application-module. The JOOQ metamodel for `shared` is generated in complete isolation from the rest, so during the code-generation for `shared`, a foreign key from `INVOICE` (module `billing`) to `FILE_STORAGE` (module `shared`) will not be visible to the JOOQ generator. Thus, the above constructor is missing on the `FILE_STORAGE` side but not on the `INVOICE` side of the JOOQ model and we end up with compilation errors in `Invoice` from `billing`'s JOOQ model.

**Question**

Short of duplicating the JOOQ model for `shared` in 10+ application modules, is there any solution to this issue? Why aren't these constructors generated unconditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the current implementation (jOOQ 3.10.0) is to prevent "excessive" code generation in cases where there are only few foreign key constraints in a large schema. I.e. there's only little gain in having this limitation.

The fact that there are compilation errors in generated code in your setup hints that this limitation is effectively wrong. It should be removed again from jOOQ 3.12.0 and 3.11.1:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7573

A workaround could be to generate all schemas and remove the unwanted code using a post-processor.